# warning: No toolsets are configured

Tags: software-installation, application-development, compiling, boost

I am new for ubuntu environment as well as `moses`, I tried to install `moses` and `boost` but when I tried to run the following command on moses directory i found the following warning, please help me what shall I do?

```
administrator@HPC-Lab-2:/home/samrawit/moses/moses/mosesdecoder$ ./bjam --with-boost=~/home/samrawit/moses/moses/boost_1_55_0 -j4
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘CreateProbingPT2’: File exists
warning: No toolsets are configured.
warning: Configuring default toolset "gcc".
warning: If the default is wrong, your build may not work correctly.
warning: Use the "toolset=xxxxx" option to override our guess.
warning: For more configuration options, please consult
warning: http://boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/advanced/configuration.html
NOT BUILDING MOSES SERVER!
Performing configuration checks

    - Shared Boost             : yes (cached)
    - Static Boost             : yes (cached)
Not building Moses2
...patience...
...patience...
...found 4726 targets...
SUCCESS
```

Comment: What is moses? Where did you get it from? What were the installation instructions and did you follow them?

Comment: moses is an application for Statistical machine translation, it decodes translation models and language models for translation system. yes I followed what the instruction says.  for more info see http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual problem you are trying to address with this post?  Based on the output you provided it appears the task completed SUCCESSFULLY.

WARNINGs are typically not errors but important messages that may be useful in troubleshooting a potential problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels for a description of the different log levels using in LINUX.

To remove the warnings you should follow the instructions to configure your compiler as per the url provided in the messages http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html